# Send multiple files in HTTP request using RAML

Tags: mule, httprequest, anypoint-studio, raml

I am writing an HTTP POST request using RAML and need to write it to be able to send multiple files in the request.  The number of files might be different each time so need it to be dynamic.  How do I do this?

This will eventually be used with Anypoint Studio 6.2 and Mule 3.8.3

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **RAML version 0.8**, try below construct.It is having **repeat** property which specify possiblilty of multiple uploads

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: FileUploadExample
baseUri: localhost
/uploadMultipleFile:
  description: Uploads Multiple file 
  post:
    body:
        multipart/form-data:
         formParameters:
             file:
               description: The file to be uploaded. Supported Formats are gif, jpeg, jpg, png etc.
               required: true
               type: file
               repeat: true
```

If you are using **RAML version 1.0** 
Since **repeat** is inside the **RAML 0.8 specification** ,it is removed in RAML 1.0 in favour for RAML data *types abstraction*.
So for RAML 1.0 ,you can use something similar to below construct.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: FileUploadExample
baseUri: localhost
types:
  MultiUploadFileType:
       properties:
          file:
            description: The file to be uploaded. Supported Formats are gif, jpeg, jpg, png etc.
            required: true
            type: file

/uploadMultipleFile:
  description: Uploads Multiple file
  post:
    body:
      multipart/form-data:
        type: MultiUploadFileType[]
        minItems: 1
```

Here  , we **use type abstraction to define a type and then use it as a array along with multipart/form-data**