# Mulesoft Rest Web service

Tags: mule-esb

I creating Rest Web service for fetching attachment file through http and storing file to local drive so i need filename dynamically as it is come in http request 
My flow as follows

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
    <set-payload value="#[payload.getInputStream() ]" doc:name="Get Inputstream from Payload"/>
        <logger message="}}}#[message.inboundAttachments['payload']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>           

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="F:\mule_data\e_files" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="abcd.jpg"/>
    </foreach>
<set-payload value="{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;success&quot;}" doc:name="Generate JSON Response" />

</flow>
```

Here outputPattern="abcd.jpg" is harcoded so i need filename and format which coming through request
  Please help

i refer from https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/soap-rest-attachments/

Answer (score 1):

Please go through my answer in the question linked below.

[How send a file in an HTTP request and upload it to file server via FTP in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786806/how-send-a-file-in-an-http-request-and-upload-it-to-file-server-via-ftp-in-mule/46788029#46788029)

Once you are able to read/get the attachment file,you can get all the metadata associated with file.For reading **name** you can do following-

use **#[payload.dataSource.part.fileName]** to get name of attachment.