# Sending Multipart Requests in mule

Tags: mule, multipart

I have an Database connector from the selected data i use to create a file and I want to do HTTP post with file (created from the selected data in csv) along with other data (text) as attached in the screenshot. According to the mule documentation, the payload must be an outbound attachment which I am doing by using Set Attachment property. With this approach, I am setting the Content-Type for one of my attachment as application/CVS (as my file is of CVS type) and as text/plain for the other parameter. Any thoughts on achieving this? I have attached the screenshot of how the request looks like in Postman.
[image]

Below is the config XML..!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd">
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="CSFMDataSource" name="CSFMDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
            <spring:property name="user" value="XXCCS_OSB_O"/>
            <spring:property name="password" value="OrG2_BtN"/>
            <spring:property name="dataSourceName" value="ds"/>
            <spring:property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=1)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-nprd-2023)(PORT=1541)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DV3CSF_SRVC_OTH.cisco.com)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
    <db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" dataSource-ref="CSFMDataSource" doc:name="Oracle Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="tools-stage.cisco.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>

  <flow name="testFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
            <logger message="Log-1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT sol.SW_UPG_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
       sol.service_level,
       sol.BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID,
       sol.SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE,
       sol.SERVICE_END_DATE,
       0 Net_Price,
       sol.PRODUCT_ORDER_NUMBER,
       sol.SERIAL_NUMBER,
       sol.SW_UPG_FULFILLMENT_PID,
       sol.INSTALL_SITE_USE_ID,
       sii.INSTANCE_ID,
       DECODE (sii.INSTANCE_ID, 'Yes', 'No') softline,
       '1232' cs_cse_number,
       lg.error_message
  FROM apps.XXCSS_SFM_ORDER_LINES sol,
       apps.XXCSS_SFM_ERROR_LOG lg,
       apps.XXCSS_SFM_INSTANCE_INTERFACE sii
        WHERE     1 = 1
       AND sol.order_type = 'INNVO_LINE'
       AND sol.entitlement_status IN ('CSFM_ERROR', 'QA_FAILED')
       --AND lg.so_header_id = sol.header_id
       --AND lg.so_line_id = sol.line_id
       AND lg.ERROR_TYPE = 'ERROR'
       AND sol.header_id = sii.so_header_id(+)
       AND sol.line_id = sii.so_line_id(+)
       AND lg.sfdc_case_req = 'Y'
       AND lg.sfdc_case_no IS NULL]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="38e67a04-7f03-4261-a450-72b69ae0fff1">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID: payload01.BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID as :number,
    CS_CSE_NUMBER: payload01.CS_CSE_NUMBER,
    ERROR_MESSAGE: payload01.ERROR_MESSAGE,
    INSTALL_SITE_USE_ID: payload01.INSTALL_SITE_USE_ID as :number,
    INSTANCE_ID: payload01.INSTANCE_ID,
    NET_PRICE: payload01.NET_PRICE as :number,
    PRODUCT_ORDER_NUMBER: payload01.PRODUCT_ORDER_NUMBER,
    SERIAL_NUMBER: payload01.SERIAL_NUMBER,
    SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE: payload01.SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE,
    SERVICE_END_DATE: payload01.SERVICE_END_DATE,
    SERVICE_LEVEL: payload01.SERVICE_LEVEL,
    SOFTLINE: payload01.SOFTLINE,
    SW_UPG_CONTRACT_NUMBER: payload01.SW_UPG_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
    SW_UPG_FULFILLMENT_PID: payload01.SW_UPG_FULFILLMENT_PID
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="filedata" value="#[payload]" contentType="application/csv" doc:name="Attachment"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="casedata" value="{ &quot;Origin&quot;:&quot;Web&quot;, &quot;CaseNumber&quot;:&quot;33315931584&quot;, &quot;SearchCCOID&quot;:&quot;vimerugu&quot;}" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attachment"/>
        <set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/cvcm/was70/pwc036/caseApi/updateCaseAttach/33315931584" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" parseResponse="false">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Basic Q1BFQ2FzZUFQSS5nZW46Y2FzZTFnZW4="/>

            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
        <logger message="#[flowVars.varCaseUpdate]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

       <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Log_DB">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into XXCSS_SFM_OSB_EXECUTION_LOG (PROCESS_STATUS) values ('SFDCCaseCreationService-Exception')]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
            <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="SFDCCaseCreation- Exception">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into XXCSS_SFM_CESB_LOG_ERROR ( LOG_ERROR_ID,SERVICE_NAME,SERVICE_TYPE,SERVICE_ACTIVITY,SERVICE_PAYLOAD,LOG_ERROR_STATUS,
LOG_ERROR_MESSAGE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE,ERROR_DETAILS,LOG_ERROR_SEVERITY,SUGGESTED_ACTION,NOTIFY_MAIL,NOTIFY_COUNT,ATTRIBUTE_1,
ATTRIBUTE_2,ATTRIBUTE_3,ATTRIBUTE_4,ATTRIBUTE_5,ATTRIBUTE_6,ATTRIBUTE_7,ATTRIBUTE_8,ATTRIBUTE_9,ATTRIBUTE_10,CREATED_BY,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,BATCH_ID)
values ('1000','SFDCCaseCreationService','SFDCCaseCreationServiceType','SFDCCaseCreationServiceActivity','SFDCCaseCreationServicePayload','ERROR','','Error_Code','Error_Message',
#[exception.getSummaryMessage()],'Critical','','NA',3,'','','','','','','','','','','SFDCCaseCreationService',sysdate,'SFDCCaseCreationService',sysdate,'1000')]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is there any relevant code you could add to the question?

Comment: It looks like you have a scenario here, but you need to provide more information about the problem, response messages, logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below link helps you.It tells how to read multiple files and process them.You can send them to required endpoint instead of FTP

[How send a file in an HTTP request and upload it to file server via FTP in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786806/how-send-a-file-in-an-http-request-and-upload-it-to-file-server-via-ftp-in-mule/46788029#46788029)

Comment: We need to send it over the HTTP request only and then capture the response.